# cURL POST error with Printful API: BadRequest, File array not specified

Tags: php, api, curl, post

I'm trying to run a very basic API request based on Printful's documentation to generate a shirt mockup (https://www.printful.com/docs/generator).  I'm trying to follow their format as closely as possible, but I'm getting an error and need help.  Thank you a ton in advance!

Error response:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["code"]=>
  int(400)
  ["result"]=>
  string(24) "File array not specified"
  ["error"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["reason"]=>
    string(10) "BadRequest"
    ["message"]=>
    string(24) "File array not specified"
  }
}
```

From the following code (key has been removed):

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Printful API - Mockup Generator Basic Test</h2>";
$key = "##########:#############";

// Set URL variables
$shirt_mockup_generator_url = "https://api.printful.com/mockup-generator/create-task/71";
$image_url = "https://wiesmann.codiferes.net/share/bitmaps/test_pattern.png";

// Set body of request
$body = [
  'variant_ids' => [4012, 4013, 4014, 4017, 4018, 4019],
  'format'=> 'jpg',
  'files' => [
      [
        'placement' => 'front',
        'image_url' => $image_url,
        'position'=> [
          'area_width' => 1800,
          'area_height' => 2400,
          'width' => 1800,
          'height' => 1800,
          'top' => 300,
          'left' => 0
        ]
      ],
      [
        'placement' => 'back',
        'image_url' => $image_url,
        'position' => [
          'area_width' => 1800,
          'area_height' => 2400,
          'width' => 1800,
          'height' => 1800,
          'top' => 300,
          'left' => 0
        ]
      ]
    ]
];

$curl = curl_init();

// POST method
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

// Authentication:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key);

// API URL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $shirt_mockup_generator_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Run and close cURL
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Format and output response
$response = json_decode($result);
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo '<pre>' , var_dump($response) , '</pre>';

?>
```

EDIT: Here's the section on their API doc I'm trying to replicate

**POST to https://api.printful.com/mockup-generator/create-task/71 with body parameters:** 
[image]

Comment: The PHP itself looks good; it seems to be a difference between what you're sending and what they're expecting. Are you sure they're not looking for something (stupid) like `file` instead of `files`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Could be, for sure; I get the sense that I've perhaps structured the body incorrectly.  I copied the section wholesale from their example (edited for PHP), but then I wrapped it in an array.  Maybe a different data structure...? Not sure what else would make sense

Answer (score 2):

It's not made obvious by their documentation, but you need to `json_encode` the POST parameters.

Change your line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
```

to this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  Answer is right here for anyone else looking